# Limit File Size and File Type

Tags: laravel, validation, filesize

how can I limit the file size and file type on my Controller? I'm tried different ways but shouldn't work.

This is my Controller :

```
public function add_presentation_detail(Request $request){
$start_date     = $request->start_date;
$input_file     = $request->file;

$nik    = Sentinel::getUser()->nik;

$data   = AccelerateMentee::select(
    'accelerate_mentee.*',
    'accelerate_rotation.start_date',
    'accelerate_rotation.id as id_rotation'
)
->leftJoin('accelerate_rotation', 'accelerate_rotation.id_mentee', '=', 'accelerate_mentee.id')
->where([
    ['accelerate_mentee.nik', '=', $nik],
    ['accelerate_rotation.status', '<>', 'approved']
])
->first();

if (!empty($request->file) && $request->hasFile('file')) {
    
    $filename       = $input_file->getClientOriginalName();
    $new_filename   = "presentation_" . "-" . $filename;
    $upload_file    = $input_file->storeAs('public/accelerate/',$new_filename);

} else {

    $new_filename = null;

}
$update = AccelerateRotation::where('id', '=', $data->id_rotation)
->update([
    'status'            => 'submitted',
    'panel_time_start'  => $start_date,
    'file'              => $new_filename,
]);

return redirect()->back();
```

Thank you, I'm so confused right now.

Comment: Did you try laravel validation?

Comment: You should to try laravel validation and validation rules will be like that `$validated = $request->validate([
        'file' => 'file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|size:1024',
    ]);`

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the input data from the user's input. You can not trust the user. That's why you should use Laravel Validation. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation) you can read more about it. Before you use your file store, you should validate user input. If everything goes well then you should proceed and use this validated inputs.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'file' => 'required|size:1024' // Validate that an uploaded file is exactly 1024 kilobytes...

]);
```

Then you use this validated data